# Datastage Designer and Sequential File Location

Tags: linux, datastage

Having been thrown into the deep end with DataStage/QualityStage, I'm working on an IBM tutorial on Parallel Jobs and having a hard time getting traction. I think some of the problem is that I'm used to Microsoft conventions. I am even finding the IBM forums difficult to navigate.

The tutorial calls for the import of a CSV file which I have on my workstation, but the properties dialog of the Sequential File stage (which is my data source) seems to map only to directories on the Linux server.

If I need to get a network connection to a shared folder on the Linux server or get a Windows share mounted on the Linux box, I will start that ball rolling, but I'm hoping not as that will be a bit of a bureaucratic nightmare here. How can I import the file from my Windows client? I would be grateful if someone can point me down the right path.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to prepare an ftp transfer and use the ftp stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright 
assuming that your datastage SERVER is installed on a linux box ABC. 
the easiest way would be to use an FTP tool like winscp (which would give you a nice GUI windows one showing your machine and the other one showing the server)
and from there you can drag and drop the file from your machine to the server folder you like. 
Now to do that you would need access to the server on which Datastage is installed.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions from jclozano and Ashish Devassy are both sound, although they require assistance from system administrators to establish permissions for FTP connections. The FTP stage has a lot to recommend it as far as automation.

When I approached my administrators (prior to seeing these suggestions) for help, they just made me an admin on the Linux box so I could solve the problem myself. What I did was create a share on the workstation running the Designer client and then mapped a folder in /mnt to it. I then copied the files to another folder in /home so I could manage the read/write permissions. That was a problem in the /mnt folder, I imagine having something to do with being a Linux to Windows connection.